# permutations of 10 objects in a subset contains similar elements

Tags: probability, permutations

A board that is divided into 15 different places, and we want to place 10 components on this board such that each component is placed in a section; knowing that those components are divided into 4 components of the same type - type 1 - and the other 6 components of another type - type 2- .

How many different designs are possible of those components when placed on the board?

So here is my solution and thoughts:
First I found the permutations of these 10 components:
10!/(4!6!) = 210 order

then I found how many subset of size 10 places can be taken from the 15 place of the board, using 15!/10!(15-10)! = 3003

then each order of the component can take one of the layouts that's of size 10, thus 3003*210 = 630630 design

But I'm really not sure since I didn't work much on probabilities problems.

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the body!!!

Comment: @barakmanos I thought it's relevant, I'm sorry I will change it now.

Comment: They're still different. Are you looking to calculate probability of something (and if yes, then what is that "something")? Or are you just asking how many different arrangements there are?

Comment: @barakmanos yes I'm looking to find number of arrangements, thank you for your answer it's more clear to me how to do such problems now.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #$1$:**

Multiply the following:

- The number of ways to choose $4$ out of $15$ sections for the first type
- The number of ways to choose $6$ out of the remaining $11$ sections for the second type

Hence the answer is $\binom{15}{4}\cdot\binom{11}{6}=630630$.

---

**Option #$2$:**

Multiply the following:

- The number of ways to choose $6$ out of $15$ sections for the second type
- The number of ways to choose $4$ out of the remaining $9$ sections for the first type

Hence the answer is $\binom{15}{6}\cdot\binom{9}{4}=630630$.